# Replace audio/video enclosure with player?

Tags: plugin-development, media, embed, videos, audio

Current state: I'm parsing XML feeds into the front end and/or the back end (Admin UI), but not into the DB.
Inside those feeds i place mp3- and video content, currently only as plain text (no link, no player).

Future goal: I want to change the above behavior so visitors can watch/listen to video/audio content.

What I'm searching for: builtin (wp core) function(s) that load a (wp core) player for audio and/or video files in the feed.
What I'm not searching for: A regular expression/regex to replace the current text (link).

The solution should be independent from any plugins, themes or any other third party code.

**Edit: Shortly ma question, maybe you understand my problem easier**

Is there a way to see \'enclosures\' from RSS feeds? I would like to use the images as thumbnails and view a player for video and audio enclosures. Here is an example feed item with enclosure...

```
<item>
    <title>New Ferrari FF video</title>

    <link>http://www.evo.co.uk/news/evonews/264793/ferrari_ff_new_pictures_and_video.html</link>
    <description>Ferrari releases a new, action-packed and undisguised video of its FF supercar. Video and new pictures here</description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 25 Feb 2011 15:04:58 +0000</pubDate>
    <enclosure url="http://www.evo.co.uk/images/front_picture_library_UK/dir_853/car_photo_426559_23.jpg" length="5420" type="image/jpeg"/>
</item>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just reading wrong, but I don't at all get what you're trying to ask...

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad.
Short: I will replace the enclosure of audio and video with a player; for play audios/videos on the website after read xml.

Comment: Are you asking alter some data (via xml) that you are importing into WordPress so that any audio/video files that are enclosed in the xml file are automatically replaced by code allowing end-users to play the files rather than download them?

Comment: i will not alter the data, i will use the audio and video enclosure code and replace with a player to use the medias for the readers on frontend. But i dont import the feed in the database, only read via simplepie to view inside a page.

Comment: add infos: I want to parse newsfeeds containing video player markup. The markup should be replaced by my own player. Are there any native WordPress functions to do that? Or, at least, something faster than regex?

Comment: Can you add examples of that markup you want to parse to your question? And probably what it looks like after being replaced. Regex are normally pretty fast but are pre-xml-era. The DomDocument XML stuff is quite well working and there is FluentDOM which makes things really easy - especially with PHP 5.3 (works with 5.2 as well).

Comment: @hakre: now i have add an feed with enclosure and code example to my question. I parse via WP Core - SimplePie. I search for an solution, thats replace this on a page to use a player for readers of the page. The php version is not relevant, i will include this in a free plugin and check before for this version, only for this version is this function active. THANKS

Comment: @bueltge: Do you currently use the SimplePie class to display the feed? Because this already contains support for getting enclosure data from an item, you won't need an extra XML parser for that. Now is your question how to get the enclosure information or how to show the player? Can you add the code you currently use to display the feed in your site?

Comment: @Jan: yes, im parse with simpepie and i will show the player for the enclosure-Tag with audio or video to use this online, on the page. I use the plugin RSSImport and other custom code with fetch_feed() from WordPress core.

Comment: @bueltge: Am I correct when I understand your question as: "Given a URL to a media file (audio, video), how can I display a media player using only WP core functions?"

Comment: @Jan: Yes, that's what he wants to do.

Comment: @bueltge: WordPress doesn't include a media player. Well, it used to, but [it will be removed in 3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14647) because the original license is unclear and the sources cannot be found. So you'll have to find a hosted player that can play arbitrary files, to embed it in your site.

Comment: @Jan: thanks, the ticket is very interesting, but i think its give a project for my requerement. But i see on this discussion, no people use this or has an solution for a easy include in the custom projects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe part of what you're looking for is the WP_Embed class defined in wp-includes/media.php. It implements a framework for automatically replacing urls with the output of embed handlers. I'm afraid you'll have to do the deeper research yourself (this was apparently introduces in 2.9.0, so documentation might still be thin).

I doubt Wordpress core comes with a player solution or will ever do so. It would seem it installs a single default embed handler for googlevideo urls. For anything else you'll have to write and register your own embed handler and if you want to host the files and player yourself, you'll either need a 3rd party player (plugin) or rely on HTML5 video/audio tags.

Ahh...and the WP_Embed class seems to get added as a callback to the 'the_content' filters by default, so you shouldn't need to do so manually. At least that's what it looks like here. ;-)

IF on the other hand you are not trying to replace URLs pointing to your media files, but rather complete tag enclosures like `<video></video>` or `<embed></embed>` and so on, then you'll have to rely on regex or write your PHP XML manipulation functions, as i'm pretty sure Wordpress doesn't natively come with functions to do something like that.

You could, however, combine that with above, making your job a bit easier, by regex-erasing everything within those tags and the tags themselves and only leaving the url. If you regsiter the filter callback that does that with a higher priority than 10 on the 'the_content' filter hook, the WP_Embed filter callback will then react on these URLs and you can do the rest using the WP_Embed framework.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have search in this class and the wp_embed works well with the url and oEmbed interface. But i will see also in the core of WordPress for an solution. My opinio for this questian was: maybe someone has to experience and i can use this experience.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to replace XML Data I think the best way would be to use the XMLParser functions or the Simple XML Functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

I dont have any examples at hand but there should be plenty around on the web.

Answer to comment
Simplepie seems to be able to edit contents before output like this: http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_edit_part_of_the_feed_before_parsing_it.

If your video is an url from the major video streamers that use oEmbed you might be able to use http://codex.wordpress.org/oEmbed this to get the video players and inject these into the simplepie stream, but this is pure speculation on my part. I havent worked with either classes.

Comment: it is not a my problem to read the xml, but i will replace the enclosure of audio and video with a player; for play audios/videos on the website after read xml. Current i read the xml with the simplepie of the WordPress core, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the services hosting the original media don't support OEmbed, then you're going to have to manually install your own players. There's no built-in function that will give you media players that easily. If they *do* support OEmbed, then all you need to do is wrap your links in [embed] shortcodes with a content filter, and maybe add a filter to whitelist the OEmbed services.

Comment: yes, i know this solution; but it is not possible to add all oEmbed-services, they WordPress knows, to parse the feed and when its an services, like youtube, inside the feed is, than replace this with a player? The feeds are changed, the plugin was used from many people on many sites and all ask for an soltuion to replace the enclosures with a player. It is not possible for me to add all solutions for all services, i cant all services. Thanks for you reply

Comment: maybe it is possible i add a hook after parsing feed, like the_content on WP and add the folow functions?
add_filter( 'my_hook', array( $wp_embed, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'my_hook', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed'), 8 );

Comment: You could run into difficulties with this if the oEmbed service recognizes *the URL of the page containing the media*, but not *the URL of the media file*. Take YouTube: the oEmbed recognizes [`http://(www\.)?youtube.com/watch.*`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L40), but this will not match the actual media file URL.