# post formats - how to get the relevant content part?

Tags: post-formats

The following post formats got a specific type of content part that should get displayed:

- Audio
- Video
- Link

### Questions:

**A)** What is the exact content (element) that is meant to get displayed for video & audio?

**B)** How would you get the relevant part of the post content that represents the post format?

**C)** What would you do with the rest of the content?

**D)** How would you know which format a audio/video player needs as there's nothin built in?

---

*Note (ad C): How would a user know that she/he should only post eg. a "link" (post format) and not a link inside a text?*

*Note (ad D): [As already asked by @bueltge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/replace-audio-video-enclosure) there's no player.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no convention or consensus on any of these questions.

In my own Theme, Oenology, I use the standard template tag `the_content()` to get the content for almost every Post Format type. The exception is Images and Galleries, where I pull the image out separately, and use `the_excerpt()` as the image caption/gallery description.

A) They are intended to display whatever content is added to the Post.

B) Use `the_content()`, just as you would with a "standard" Post

C) Display it, either as per normal, or using some creativity for certain post format types. If you develop a Theme that makes certain assumptions about what content applies to specific Post Format types, then provide documentation within the Theme to explain those assumptions.

D) You can't know. I just leave the raw link to the audio, and leave it up to the end user to choose an Audio Player Plugin.